# Как обновить левый/правый Fragment во ViewPager при выборе текущего?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

При перелистывании фрагментов - предыдущий хранится в памяти. Как сделать, чтобы он там не хранился, а обновлялся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете переопределить в каждом фрагменте метод, в коем сможете определить, что фрагмент более не виден пользователю (т.е. он находится слева/справа от текущего) и в этот момент обновить фрагмент как вам угодно. Решение [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25676323/3212712):

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // сейчас фрагмент виден юзеру
    }else{
       // Обновляйте тут, фрагмент не видим юзеру
       if(getView()!=null) { /* тут ListView не будет null */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня не получается присвоить listView адаптер, так как на listView NullPointerException.

Comment: @Влад, попробуйте обновлённый ответ.

Comment: А если (getView()!=null) всегда будет false, то как в этом случае я могу обновить listView? Существуют ли еще способы обновления фрагмента или пересоздания, чтобы запускался onCreateView&. Или может что-то с viewPager можно сделать?

Comment: Предложенный способ обновит фрагмент сразу после его замены следующим. Также вы можете в адаптере хранить ссылки на фрагменты в списке и в нужный момент прямо вызвать их методы. Но они могут быть не подсоеденены к активити в данный момент. Тогда лучше обновлять данные в них, а не перерисовывать списки.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) Ну это если вы используете фрагменты