# В TabLayout cрабатывают методы OnCreateView из других Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Есть TabLayout с ViewPager
В TabLayout  3 закладки. 
При выборе закладки или пролистывании срабатывает метод OnCreateView из других
Fragments. В каждом фрагменте указал тост чтобы было наглядно видно.
Ниже ссылка на проект. Почему так происходит и как сделать чтобы при нажатии на вкладки срабатывал тот метод который выбрали?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ViewPager` по умолчанию загружает отображаемую страницу + страницы слева и справа (по одной). Именно это вы и наблюдаете - это стандартное и ожидаемое поведение. Если вам нужно событие отображения страницы на экране - [смотрите в сторону](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498508/17609) `Fragment#setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible)`

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    Log.d("TAG", "setUserVisibleHint isVisibleToUser: " + isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser) {
        //тут фрагмент виден юзеру
    }
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
}
```